# Autofilter using our own variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a  problem with autofilter using macro. The idea is how to use autofilter with macro using spesific criteria from myself. This is the original code for my autofilter:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$P$100").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    "Call Success Rate"
```

I tried to make a variable called "temp" to manipulate the criteria:

```
Dim temp As String
```

then declare the temp

```
temp = Call Fail Rate
```

but when I run the macro, the autofilter didn't recognize "temp" variable.

So how to make this autofilter recognize my own variable?

Comment: you need to put quotes around the string `"Call Fail Rate"`

Comment: ah my bad, forgot to put the quotes. Thanks for the help Scoot